# page keeps on posting to iframe when removed

Tags: jquery, iframe

$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#uploadSubmit").bind("click", function () {
                //edit below to suit
                var src = "uploader.php";
                //end
                var results = '';
                $("#uploader").append(results);
                $("#uploadResult").html('Uploading please wait... ');
                $("#uploaderIframe").load(function () {
                    var iframeHtml = $('#uploaderIframe').contents().find("body").html();
                    $("#uploadResult").html(iframeHtml);
                    $("#uploaderIframe").remove();
                });
            }); 
        });

works perfectly but the main page keeps loading once the iframe is removed. Any know why and how i can terminate the loading?

Answer (score 0):

thought this would work but didn't

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.name = "main";
    $("#uploadSubmit").bind("click", function () {
        //edit below to suit
        var src = "uploader.php";
        //end
        var results = '<iframe src="' + src + '" name="uploader" id="uploaderIframe"></iframe>';
        $("#uploader").append(results);
        $("#uploadResult").html('Uploading please wait... <img src="images/loader.gif" />');
        $("#uploaderIframe").load(function () {
            var iframeHtml = $('#uploaderIframe').contents().find("body").html();
            $("#uploadResult").html(iframeHtml);
            $("#uploaderIframe").remove();
            main.execCommand('Stop');
            main.stop();
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```